# Parameter expansion not working when used inside Awk on one of the column entries

Tags: bash, awk, variable-expansion

System: Linux. Bash 4.

I have the following file, which will be read into a script as a variable:

```
/path/sample_A.bam A 1
/path/sample_B.bam B 1
/path/sample_C1.bam C 1
/path/sample_C2.bam C 2
```

I want to append "_string" at the end of the filename of the first column, but before the extension (.bam). It's a bit trickier because of containing the path at the beginning of the name.

**Desired output:**

```
/path/sample_A_string.bam A 1
/path/sample_B_string.bam B 1
/path/sample_C1_string.bam C 1
/path/sample_C2_string.bam C 2
```

**My attempt:** 
I did the following script (I ran: bash script.sh):

```
List=${1};
awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '{ $1 = "${1%.bam}" "_string.bam" }1' < ${List} ;
```

And its output was:

```
${1%.bam}_string.bam
${1%.bam}_string.bam
${1%.bam}_string.bam
${1%.bam}_string.bam
```

**Problem:**
I followed the idea of using awk for this substitution as in this thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148114/how-to-add-words-to-an-existing-column , but the parameter expansion of ${1%.bam} it's clearly not being recognised by AWK as I intend. Does someone know the correct syntax for that part of code? That part was meant to mean "all the first entry of the first column, except the last part of .bam". I used ${1%.bam} because it works in Bash, but AWK it's another language and probably this differs. Thank you!

Comment: You need to have imported `$1` in the context of `Awk`. Your attempt does not work because `awk` does not recognize `$1` as a place-holder for the content stored.

Comment: $1 is not meant to be calling a variable named "$1", but rather it is supposed to be the first column of the file (given that the file has rows and columns). The problem is different here and that thread didn't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, could you please try following.

```
val="_string"
awk -v value="$val" '{sub(".bam",value"&")} 1'  Input_file
```

***Brief explanation:*** `-v value` means passing shell variable named `val` value to awk variable `variable` here. Then using `sub` function of `awk` to substitute string `.bam` with string value along with `.bam` value which is denoted by `&` too. Then mentioning `1` means print edited/non-edtied line.

***Why OP's attempt didn't work:*** Dear, OP. in `awk` we can't pass variables of shell directly without mentioning them in `awk` language. So what you are trying will NOT take it as an `awk` variable rather than it will take it as a string and printing it as it is. I have mentioned in my explanation above how to define shell variables in `awk` too.

***NOTE:*** In case you have multiple occurences of `.bam` then please change `sub` to `gsub` in above code. Also in case your Input_file is TAB delmited then use `awk -F'\t'` in above code.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 How would you solve this with a regular expression? (in the case that instead of ".bam", you want to substitute any extension) (imagine you apply that to a list of text files and some are .bam and some are .fastq)

Comment: @msimmer92, I haven't checked it but can you please try replacing `sub(".bam",value"&")` to `gsub(/.bam|.fastq/,value"&")` and let me know then?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the paramter expansion you applied on `$1` won't apply inside `awk` as the entire command 
body of the `awk` command is passed in `'..'` which sends content *literally* without applying any
shell parsing. Hence the string `"${1%.bam}"` is passed as-is to the first column.

You can do this completely in `Awk`

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS }{ n=split($1, arr, "."); $1 = arr[1]"_string."arr[2] }1'  file
```

The code basically splits the content of `$1` with delimiter `.` into an array `arr` in the context of `Awk`. So the part of the string upto the first `.` is stored in `arr[1]` and the subsequent split fields are stored in the next array indices. We re-construct the filename of your choice by concatenating the array entries with the `_string` in the filename part without extension.

Comment: This also gives me the output I wanted. I selected the other answer as the main answer because it was the first one (and also the syntax is easier to understand and more straightforward, in my opinion). But which one is more correct or better? In case this one is, I will switch it.

Comment: @msimmer92: I'll leave it up-to you to decide the one that you find it most useful. At the end of the day, you need to take the one that you find easy to work with or easy to adapt in your further coding efforts

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i 's/\.bam/_string\.bam/g' myfile.txt
```

It's a single line with sed.  Just replace the .bam with _string.bam

Comment: It also works, but you should maybe edit and clarify that the -i edits the original file. In my case I didn't want to do that (I want to redirect that output to another file, so I have both), so I took out the -i.

Comment: Ah.  Ok.  That's fine.  Just cat the file, pipe to the sed, and direct to a new file.

Comment: How would you solve this with a regular expression? (in the case that instead of ".bam", you want to substitute any extension) (imagine you apply that to a list of text files and some are .bam and some are .fastq) I mean, which would be the correct regular expression to use?

Comment: Well, I don't quite understand the question.  But if you want to match multiple things, you can always just add in more expressions with sed.  So if I understand your question correctly, you can do this: `cat myfile.txt | sed -e 's/\.bam/_string\.bam/g' -e 's/\.fastq/_string\.fastq/g'`

Comment: If you don't mind changing any and all file extensions in a list of text files, and the filename/extension are always the last characters of the line, you can do this: `cat myfile.txt | sed 's/\(\.[a-zA-Z]\+$\)/_string\1/g'`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way with awk :

```
awk -v a='_string' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{$1=$1 a}1' infile
```